# How to retrieve header response data in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am running on my localhost and then I submitted the form to a remote url. So, the procedure will be the following:

1. Submit a form from localhost
2. It will be redirected to remote URL
3. from Remote URL, it will send a response back to the localhost

I can retrieve the localhost header response.

```
mounted(){
     window.axios.get('http://localhost:8080')
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response.headers)
        })
}
```

But, the response data is not correct since it is the data inside the localhost header. What I want is to retrieve the header response from remote(web) url. So, I changed the URL *window.axios.post('remote_url')*

But the problem is, there is a CORS privacy error.

[image]

I want to get the **order_id**. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

you need to allow CORs in your remote server check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

for more info.
Also, check this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50949631/9216024)