# React CORS policy issue with an Axios API in localhost. How can I resolve it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, rxjs

I'm using an Axios module in my React app, and I am using to API POST method.

Like this:

```
axios.request({
    method: "POST",
    url,
    responseType: "jsonp",
    data: payload,
    ...config
});
```

But I get an error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://0.0.0.0/api/ak' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
> xhr.js:160 POST http://0.0.0.0/api/ak net::ERR_FAILED

Where am I wrong?

Comment: its a famous problem, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50949631/8945943 will help you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vite then add this to your vite.config.js

```
  server: {
    proxy: {
      "/api": "http://localhost:3000",
    },
  },
```

here localhost:3000 is my backend URL and I can use localhost:3000/api/(home/user...) to get the data.

In react app

```
const res = await axios.get("/api/users");
```

This worked for me. Remember to restart your react server after configuration

Comment: Did you try this with different domains?

Comment: What do you mean by different domains? I only used these configs in localhost so far

Comment: The question is about a CORS error, that is, ,Cross-Origin Resource Sharing. If you tested with a single domain, then the problem is not reproducible for you, even if you failed to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

Setup package CORS in your Express server

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors