# CORS issue in Reactjs after login

Tags: reactjs, api

Cors error is showing not getting what is problem same thing is working fine in reactnative but not in reactjs
   `export const checkUser = () => { return async (dispatch) => { const token = getCookie("userToken"); const url =`/auth/me`;
const response = await api
.post(url, { token })
.then((res) => {
return res;
})
.catch((error) => {
return error.response;
});

```
dispatch({
  type: "CHECK_USER",
  payload: response,
});
```

};
};
`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Axios having CORS issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50949594/axios-having-cors-issue)

Answer (score 0):

[Cross-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) Resource Sharing (CORS) is an HTTP-header based mechanism that allows a server to indicate any origins (domain, scheme, or port) other than its own from which a browser should permit loading resources

Now , to overcome this issue one way is to allow your origin from server ([PHP Example](https://enable-cors.org/server_php.html)) , another approach is to [setup proxy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) in your application